# How can I use/convert the touchpad, keyboard and screen of an old laptop to use them with a desktop PC?

Tags: display, hardware, monitor

Is there a common way for all the laptops' hardware, like screen, touchpad, and keyboard, that can be followed in order to use them with a desktop PC? 
What I need to do, to use screen, touchpad, and keyboard of my old laptop with my desktop PC?
Would be fine if I disassemble my laptop, then I remove the screen connector from the motherboard, and I try solder pin-by-pin of the laptop screen connector with a VGA cable? 
Is there a standard connector for laptops' screens?
Concerning the keyboard and touchpad I was thinking to do the same thing but with an USB cable, would it be ok?
The purpose of this question is also to become a sort of guide for all the people that are trying to reuse the hardware of their old laptops.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: http://lcdtovga.blogspot.de/

Comment: This question is on-topic. **consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing thes products or modifying their electronics for other uses** Ripping it out of its embedded design and modifying it for other uses counts.

Answer (score 2):

A laptop screen is usually an LCD screen with an LVDS connection (or two depending on resolution.)  This is a differential parallel data bus with data pairs and a clock pair.  The protocol is not too complicated, but you won't be soldering directly to a desktop compatible video connector without an interface board.  LVDS is pretty standard, but an interface board for your specific LCD panel will provide the proper drive voltages for the LCD and backlight.

If you search for your LCD panel, you may be able to find a controller board that will run the LCD as a desktop monitor.  That is probably your best hope, if you don't have the capability of making this yourself.

Most laptops typically have USB or PS/2 based keyboard and touchpads, although some are raw devices.  For USB style or PS/2, you just need to locate the place to connect all wires and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop keyboards and touchpads typically come in three flavors. Direct interfaces (Raw keyboard matrix and raw resistive or capacitive touchpad matrixes), PS/2 (Older), and USB (Newer). Both the PS/2 and USB types require you to find the pinout, and then can be wired to a USB cable. Some might run on 3.3v or lower instead of 5v, so you need to measure that and provide proper regulation first.

Laptop LCDs do not use VGA, or DVI, or any of the external interface types. They use a LVDS (Low Voltage Digital Signal) interface, and varies widely by panel and laptop manufacturer. But in the last few years, universal LVDS interfaces have become cheap. They are basically the same video boards you see in regular external monitors, taking VGA, DVI, HDMI to LVDS. You also need to provide the proper power, which varies by screen type and backlight type (High Voltage Inverter, or LED or whatever).

Laptop Cameras are the same thing. Typically all are USB at this point, though some take 3.3v or lower instead of 5v.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop screen will be most complicated part, because LCD controller is built into graphics cards in most cases, and **you can't extract parts responsible for driving LCD from laptop**. That makes connecting Laptop LCD to VGA complicated.

This information may be outdated, it applies to laptops that were manufactured few years ago (before HD and HDMI came out). I have not tried this with modern laptops.

**Much easier** way is disassembling **desktop LCD monitor**, which have VGA to LCD module.

Keyboards and touchpad are USB based in most cases. See other answers for more information.